# Patterns of craniofacial topology

Tags: genetics, zoology, anatomy, morphology

There are animals which are not directly related but have similar craniofacial topology.

For example: koala, donkey, mouse, turtle, parrot all have features seemingly belonging to same topology, especially by baby species.
Mostly it is features like bridge, bridge to eye socket position, nostrils, upper jaw.

Here is a sketch of what I see as a pattern:
[image]

Pronounced bridge, eye sockets on the same centerline with the bridge base. Nostrils and upper jaw center area.

Interesting is that there are other "groups" of species that also seem to have their own pattern.
E.g. cats and owls.
It appears to me that there are several basic patterns that can be observed through many species, and thus
species can be classified in such way.

Are there studies of craniofacial topologies that have connections with patterns and such classifications?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean? Similar compared to what?

Comment: If it's not a coincidence (which is correct) and you don't think evolution is the cause, what do you think is the reason mammals (kind of) look alike? (Personally, deer and koalas don't resemble each other very much to me, but if you mean, hair, bilateral symmetry, eyes, noses, ears, upper and lower jaws, etc., then yes, I agree.)

Comment: You may be interested in Paedomorphosis

Comment: @BryanKrause some clarifications are added

Comment: I'm still not really clear what you think these species have in common that other related species do not.

Comment: The [morphogenesis of craniofacial structures](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41368-020-00110-4) is a rather elaborately controlled process at both the molecular and mechanical levels. There are a [variety](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0944200604000741?via%3Dihub) of [papers](https://anatomypubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/dvdy.20833) on the [subject](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10764-015-9886-5) that you might consult. While not an expert, I suspect that this question is too broad to adequately answer all at once.

Comment: @BryanKrause that would require comparing at least two types and adding more images. I'll add it later.